# How to Pass Variables from a ReactJS application to REST API

Tags: reactjs, fetch

My React Application gets a list of buildings from a REST API; What I'm attempting to do is get those buildings that are only 10 miles from the users current location.
I'm using a geolocation-component (a ReactJS component) that returns the latitude and longitude of the user's current location. The working code is reflected below:

```
 <Geolocation
              render={({
                fetchingPosition,
                position: { coords: { latitude, longitude } = {} } = {},
                error,
                getCurrentPosition
              }) =>
                <div>
                  <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={getCurrentPosition}>Get Position</button>
                  {error &&
                    <div>
                      {error.message}
                    </div>}
                  <div>
                    <b>Latitude</b>: {latitude} <br />
                    <b>Longitude</b>: {longitude}
                  </div>
                </div>}
```

My question is, now that I'm getting the Latitude and Longitude values, how do I past those values over to the API; is this accomplished by means of implementing a Fetch using PUT to pass the latitude and longitude over to the API? ...for example, could I set up a Fetch like so and pass the values :

```
 fetch(`https://APIFile.net/api/building/`, {
method: 'PUT',
 body: JSON.stringify({
                    Latitude: latitude,
                    Longitude: longitude,
                     this.state.options)]
                }),
}
```

...if a coding example (snippet) could be provided to set me on the right path, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you have provided seems to be correct.
Note that it depends on which content-types the api accepts. If it accepts json, then what you've written is okay.